# Not getting sound for notifications in Firefox after switch to GNOME

Tags: gnome, firefox, notification

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 using Firefox and GNOME 3.14 I stopped getting desktop notifications (no visual or sound), although now that I have upgraded to GNOME 3.16 I am getting, delayed, but still the visual built-in notifications. Though still no sound, and every time that I do get pinged I notice this message in my Firefox console log:

[image]

So I am wondering why I am getting this, in what, and how to fix it?

---

### OS Information:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16
```

### Package Information:

**Firefox:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

**Gnome Shell:**

```
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.16.3-1ubuntu1~vivid1
  Candidate: 3.16.3-1ubuntu1~vivid1
  Version table:
 *** 3.16.3-1ubuntu1~vivid1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.14.4-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may be occurring because there are no packages available to decode the MP3 sound file. They may have been present on your previous installation but lost during the upgrade.

Check to see if you have a package to perform the decoding (such as `ubuntu-restricted-extras`).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32663653/5217088

Comment: Ok, I have tried installing it, and other than causing me [lots of trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678434/errors-during-installation-of-ubuntu-restricted-extras), it didn't fix anything... :P

Comment: I can see from the linked question that the installation (I am guessing has now been fixed). Does the same error message appear when a notification occurs?

Comment: Oh dear, there was I looking at my log trying to see it while people were pinging me getting annoyed at all the noise and how it was distracting me from finding the entry... :P

Comment: But on the normal Ubuntu with Unity there is no need to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` in order to hear this sound so what package do they use to play it?

Comment: It might be that a) Ubuntu doesn't need that package natively but Firefox only uses that package for its MP3 file playing or b) that installing that package "enables" that other native MP3 playing (as it needs to be restricted in other countries) to work for Firefox.