# Errors during installation of ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, software-uninstall, ubuntu-restricted-extras

During an installation of `ubuntu-restricted-extras` which was initiated by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I got these errors:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libvo-amrwbenc0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libvo-amrwbenc0_0.1.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvo-amrwbenc0:amd64 (0.1.3-1) ...
dpkg: libavcodec56:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libchromaprint0:amd64 depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not installed.
 vlc depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not installed.
 vlc-nox depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not installed.
 libavformat56:amd64 depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not installed.
```

Which slightly worried me as it seems to have uninstalled some important dependencies. Should I be worried about this? And do I need to do anything about it? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

**Information Update:**

When running `sudo apt-get install -f` the output showed no issues, and there was no output when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

And the output of `apt-cache policy libchromaprint0 libavcodec56 libavcodec-extra-56 vlc` is:

```
libchromaprint0:
  Installed: 1.2-1
  Candidate: 1.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libavcodec56:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6:11.2-1
  Version table:
     6:11.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libavcodec-extra-56:
  Installed: 6:11.2-1
  Candidate: 6:11.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 6:11.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.0-1
  Candidate: 2.2.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I attempted to install `libavcodec56` again but this is what I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra-56
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libavcodec56
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 2 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/3,046 kB of archives.
After this operation, 88.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 232524 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libavcodec-extra (6:11.2-1) ...
dpkg: libavcodec-extra-56:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libchromaprint0:amd64 depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56:amd64 is to be removed.
 vlc depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56:amd64 is to be removed.
 vlc-nox depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56:amd64 is to be removed.
 libavformat56:amd64 depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2); however:
  Package libavcodec56:amd64 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56:amd64 is to be removed.
 libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64 depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11~beta1); however:
  Package libavcodec56:am
Removing libavcodec-extra-56:amd64 (6:11.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
```

And now the output for `apt-cache policy libchromaprint0 libavcodec56 libavcodec-extra-56 vlc` is:

```
libchromaprint0:
  Installed: 1.2-1
  Candidate: 1.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libavcodec56:
  Installed: 6:11.2-1
  Candidate: 6:11.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 6:11.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libavcodec-extra-56:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6:11.2-1
  Version table:
     6:11.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.0-1
  Candidate: 2.2.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Could you check that your packages are updated `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` . Also check to see if there are some exiting dependency problems `sudo apt-get install -f` and then `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: First let's try `sudo apt-get install -f`. Add the output into your question. If that not work, give me the output of `apt-cache policy libchromaprint0 libavcodec56 libavcodec-extra-56 vlc`

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get -y install  ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: @H.Freeze: I ran all of those commands and there are no upgrades nor anything unusual in the results. Also, what does the `-a` option do?

Comment: the `-a` is shsort of --all , reconfigures all. If apt-get is working without errors , and ubuntu-restricted-extras is installed you are good to go.

Comment: @A.B.: The first command gave me nothing, I have updated my question with the output of the second.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Trying to install it again (without first removing it) just outputs that the latest version is already installed.

Comment: Remove the packages `vlc` and `libavcodec56` and start `sudo apt-get install -f` again. After that reinstall `vlc`. you have no serious problems, it is just annoying.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: I also think you are good to go as there don't appear to be any problems with your packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal is, remove to break the dependency loop and reinstall what you need.

Remove some packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo apt-get remove libchromaprint0
sudo apt-get remove libavcodec-extra-56 libavcodec-56
```

Now remove obsolete packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-restricted-extra
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: I tried to install it again recently and I got the same errors though with slightly different dependencies involved and following this answer for those didn't work... But why are there these dependency issues which did not used to be present? This really prevents people from installing this, so is this a bug which should be reported?