# Why do I always get dependancy errors when trying to install 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'?

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, software-installation, ubuntu-restricted-extras

Whenever I try to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` I always get errors similar to [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678434/errors-during-installation-of-ubuntu-restricted-extras), however the answer to that question only resolved the errors I had that time, though I get very similar errors every time I try to install it on a fresh install of Ubuntu, the same solution never works for all and I don't think I should ask here every time... I feel that that would get a bit much...

But why is it so? Why do I get these errors (because I didn't used to on previous version of Ubuntu and I'm not sure that other people do)? Is this a bug which I should report or...? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

**Information Update:**

It has been suggested that this could be due to an outdated package list, but this is not the case as I always run `sudo apt-get update` before attempting and upgrade or new installation, so I do not believe that this can be the problem unless somehow that command is not solving it.

Answer (score 0):

*I believe this could be the reason for this issue:*
On a fresh installation of Ubuntu, the list of available packets would likely date from the time the Ubuntu release was prepared.
If a package dependencies have changed since the last time the packet list was updated, your system may try to install packages that doesn't exist anymore, or eventually report dependency issues.
For this reason, it is always recommended to update the package list prior to installing new packets on a fresh installation of Ubuntu or whenever the packages list may be outdated.
You can try to update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Before installing ubuntu-restricted-extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I update the package list before attempting to install or upgrade anything so this is unlikely to be the issue, or at least, the issue isn't resolved through the running of `sudo apt-get update` (I have now updated my question to include this information).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I suggest you install  `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and accept the EULA